# Confused about highlighting active menu item on scroll (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I found this function which highlights the active menu anchors when you scroll to sections that have the same id. I understand how most of the code works, but I don't get how the window onscroll event knows how to update the right anchor tag with the .active class.

All the JS:

```js
  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
        document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
      }
    }
  };
```

From this Pen: https://codepen.io/zchee/pen/ogzvZZ

This part confuses me:

```
document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
```

I get that `setAttribute` adds a class of active to the anchor tag — but how does `querySelector` find the right anchor to update when you scroll?

I tried logging the index variable `[i]` from the (for in array loop) to get the id of the current section (onscroll) but it returns the current scroll position (as a number).

This is why I don't get why the inserted 'i' variable here: `('a[href*=' + i + ']')` represents the corresponding section id in the onscroll event.

I guess it doesn't help that I don't really understand how this forEach function operates:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
});
```

I get that it loops through all sections and pushes the `sections[e.id]` to the empty object `sections = {}` which is used later in the onscroll event — but that's where my understanding stops. :-/

I'm sorry I don't know how to phrase this question better. I've spent hours trying to wrap my head around it. I can't find any topic examples that are similar to this, but I want to understand how it works before I use it anywhere.

Would greatly appreciate some feedback! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) from W3 schools, `.querySelector` gets the first element in the document with class equalling the one being searched for.

`a[href*=#]` means the querySelector is looking for all elements containing a `#`, and in your case `'a[href*=' + i + ']'` is further specifying elements that has the current `href` of `i`.

So when you piece everything together, the code

```
for (i in sections) {
  if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
    document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
    document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
  }
}
```

looks for the element with an href equalling the current 'i' section, and sets the attribute class to active for that element.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Whenever the window is scrolled, the following happens:

1. 1) A variable is set called `scrollPosition`, which is set equal to
   the documentElement's "highest" point (or scrollTop) *OR* the
   document body's "highest" point (or scrollTop)
2. Then, for `i` in *all* sections:
   if the section is less than or equal to the scrollPostition, it changes the previously active class to null and sets the current section's class to active.

It then repeats for each section, until it arrives at the current section. So technically, every section is up to the current section is made "active" at some point (hence the console logs of each section name).

Essentially, if you were to go from "Home" to "Contact", it would remove the active class from "Home" and add it to "Portfolio", then remove it from "Portfolio" and add it to "About", before finally removing it from "About" and adding it to "Contact". That way it appears to 'know' what section you're on, but it's actually going through all of them until it reaches the right one.

(Another example: If you went from "Contact" to "Portfolio", it would remove active from "Contact" and add it to "Home", realize it's still not on the right one, then remove active from "Home" and add it to "Portfolio". This probably wouldn't work as well for a site with a bunch of sections, but it appears seamless on smaller/mid-size websites!)

There might be better ways to explain this, but I hope this 'visual' helps!

Comment: @consinepenguin thank you. 

I still don't get how it knows which is the current 'i' section. When you do console.log(i) and scroll the sections, it logs out Home first until you scroll past it — which makes sense, but as you continue to scroll it starts logging out every section id *at once* (including those that are not current) — this I don't get. 

Example: http://recordit.co/EbFc6kWCQ7

Shouldn't the log statement print out only the current section id? 

This makes it very confusing how querySelector then manages to add the active class to the actual current anchor..

Comment: @Capax Well, not exactly. What the code is doing is finding all of the `i` sections that are considered "less than or equal to" the `scrollPosition`, which is the pointer keeping track of the element you are currently on. So it makes sense that every time you scroll to a different section, you have all of the above sections print out, because you are still iterating through all of the "above" instances of `i`. I'll edit my answer and make it more understandable!

Comment: @Capax I edited the answer! If it still doesn't make sense comment and I'll try to explain it differently. It's essentially just "pretending" that it keeps track of the current section by iterating through all of them until it finds the one you're on!

Comment: thanks a lot, it makes more sense to me now! But from what I also understand, this code seems really inefficient? It does a lot of extra work just to reach to the current section. You alluded that it wouldn't work well on a bigger site. I don't like that part one bit, it seems wasteful :p I liked this code at first because it's just a few lines of code compared to most other plain JS examples solutions I've found to this feature — but perhaps at a big price! Can you recommend a way to make it more efficient? I'll definitely be looking for a way to optimize it!

Comment: No problem! And it is certainly inefficient. If you want ideas, you can look up responsive infinite scroll website templates/JQuery examples. If I stumble across something good I'll be sure to comment it here! (The main idea is you want it to dynamically keep track of what section it is on, instead of updating itself every time the window is scrolled.)

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple. 
Your variable section contains all divs with class ".section" as you see the code

```
    var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
```

Then your "sections" array is filled with all div ids and their scroll positions according to window offset value by using the code

```
    
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
    });
```

Your sections array will be like this in memory

```
    
    sections['home']=position of home 
    sections['portfolio']=position of portfolio
    sections['about']=position of about
    sections['contact']=position of contact
```

So when for loop works on sections, it gives the div id like this

```
    for (i in sections) {
    * now "i" gives the id of all div one by one
    }
```

Meanwhile in this loop querySelector will search anchor tag which contains specific href text

```
    *this will give you specific anchor tag like
    *document.querySelector('a[href*='home']')
    -> a[href*='home']
    -> a[href*='portfolio']
    -> a[href*='about']
    -> a[href*='contact']
```

I hope this will explain you easily.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say thank you @t4taurus — appreciate your input!